# Distribution of a sum in a Poisson point process

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables, poisson-process

Let $ (N_t)_{t\in\mathbb{R}^+} $ be a homogeneous Poisson point process of intensity $\lambda>0$. I'm interested in determining the distribution of
\begin{align*}
  S_t = \sum_{k=1}^{N_t} T_k,
\end{align*}
where $T_k = \inf \{t\ge 0, N_t\ge k\}$.

---

**My attempt:** Note that $S_t$ is not a conditioned Erlang distributed random variable, because $T_1,T_2,\dots$ are not independent. However, we can define $\Delta T_k = T_k-T_{k-1}$, with $T_0=0$, and rewrite $S_t$ as
\begin{align*}
  S_t = \sum_{k=1}^{N_t} k \,\Delta T_{N_t+1-k},
\end{align*}
where $\{\Delta T_k\}_k$ is a set of iid random variables that follow an exponential distribution of parameter $\lambda$.

Then, the characteristic function of $S_t \mid N_t = n$ is
\begin{align*}
  \varphi_n(x) = \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\lambda}{\lambda - ikx},
\end{align*}
and the characteristic function of $S_t$ is given by $\varphi(x) = \mathbb{E}[\varphi_{N_t}(x)]$. I tried to perform the above calculations, but without success until now. Perhaps, there is a better approach to this problem. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You could write $S_t$ as $tN_t - \int_0^t N_s ds$ but getting the exact distribution from this form seems like it will be just as much algebra. It might be easier to get the expectation and variances from this form though.

Comment: $T_k$ is the time of the $k$-th jump of $N_t\,.$ As such it is known to be the sum of $k$ exponentially distributed independent inter-arrival times $\sigma_i\,.$ Does this hint help?

Comment: @KurtG., if I'm not mistaken your $\sigma$ is equivalent to my $\Delta T$.

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed that's an interesting rewriting of $S_t$. I'll try to work with that later.

Comment: @P.S.Dester . Correct. And this is the frontier to something new.